# Python GetActiveObject - Run Photoshop Action

Tags: python-3.x, photoshop

Does anyone know how to run a pre-defined action in Photoshop using Python?

```
from comtypes.client import GetActiveObject

app = GetActiveObject("Photoshop.Application")
fileName = path
docRef = app.Open(fileName)

app.ExecuteAction("Script_Name") #not sure how to write it
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.ExecuteAction()` is a different beast — it's for executing ActionManager scrings. What you need is `app.DoAction('action_name', 'set_name')`